# How to store all data return by certain query in a table in a single string in SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have two rows in my SQL Server table as below

```
Id  Name    Address
---------------------
1   Kamal   Kathmandu
2   Rahul   Pokhara
```

I want to store these two rows a single string like this,

```
1,Kamal,Kathmandu@2,Rahul,Pokhara
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Should you not at least keep some structure around (e.g. XML)?

Comment: what if `Address` contains `@`?

Comment: Use XML Datatype of Sql-server using for xml - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT *,'@' as Sep FROM YourTable FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT Replace(Replace(stuff((SELECT ',' + node.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
              FROM   @xml.nodes('/*') AS T(node)
              FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
              , 1, 1, ''),',@,','@'),',@','');
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use this query.

```
declare @str varchar(max)
SET @str=STUFF((SELECT 
                    '@'+cast(Id as varchar)+','+Name+','+Address
                FROM tablename

                ORDER BY '@'+Id
                FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')
print @str
```

Comment: erm, where do all the extra columns come from?

Comment: sorry, answer is modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ResultString varchar(max)
SET @ResultString = ''


SELECT @ResultString = @ResultString + cast(Id as varchar) + ',' 
                       + Name + ',' + Address + '@'
FROM yourTable

SELECT @ResultString
```

@ResultString will contain single comma seprated string 
1,Kamal,Kathmandu@2,Rahul,Pokhara

Comment: You don't delimite the lines with '@', what about the trailing delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a bad idea, you are doing something wrong, but ...

```
DECLARE @badIdea nvarchar(max);
SET @badIdea = '';

SELECT @badIdea = @badIdea + 
           STR(Id) + N',' +
           Name + N',' + 
           Address + N'@'
    FROM SomeTable;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    SET @badIdea = SUBSTRING(@badIdea, 0, LEN(@badIdea) - 1);

SELECT @badIdea;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you can do it in two ways :

1. Use concatenation, like in the example here : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/25/sql-server-concat-function-in-sql-server-sql-concatenation/ . This method simple involved a query like

   SELECT str(id)+','+name+','+address FROM tblName
2. If your aim is to actually export it to a file - you can export using SSMS(which I guess you're using, since you have an MSSQL server). Right click the query results (when using a normal SELECT * FROM tblName), and click "Save Results As...". Then you can save the file into a CSV, which will output a file with the exact format you specified.

Comment: what is the `str` function?